# Have a model connect to multiple tables in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on wiring up functionality to portions of my database, and one of my first weird issues I've run into is a method of adding employees into the system.

It's not as simple as making an employee model, as my schema is a bit more involved. I structure goes something like this. I have the AspNetUsers table that connected to another table, all_users. The table, all_users, then connects to the tables companies.employees, and employees.employees.

Employee.employees contains all internal employees, and companies.employees contains all external employees. When I add a new employee to the system, if it's an external employee, it is spread across 2 tables: companies.companies, and companies.employees. The companies table houses the company name, and some other information. The employees table houses all the employees' information.

If it is an internal employee that I'm adding their information is spread out through 10 different tables, including an employees table, a phone number table, an email table, previous employment, etc.

On my add employee page, I'm wanting to basically have a dropdown asking for the company, if they select our company one form is shown, that allows them to enter all the information for an employee, across all the tables. If they select another company, they get the generic form that allows them to enter the employee's information.

I've been checking around, but haven't really seen any easy method of accomplishing this.

Comment: Are these EF code first models? Can you post your models/classes?

Comment: Why don't you just write SQL Views to encapsulate the logic into a single sql object - then you can just import the view into your model.

Comment: This is actually database first. Here is an image of my schema (slightly changed now due to a relationship change, but very similar).  http://i.imgur.com/HmU1DDL.jpg

Comment: @CamBruce but wouldn't having the views only allow me to actually view the data, not necessarily insert it? Also, I run into an issue because I can't pass information into the view, or at least I haven't figured it out yet.

Comment: I faced a similar problem on a recent project, although my schema wasn't as complex as yours. I ended up using a repository pattern, mapping a large view model that corresponded to my form to my domain (database) models, and then using Dapper to insert into the DB. Wasn't necessarily easy, but it got the job done. You could also check out AutoMapper.

Comment: I think you'r schema is too complex and trying to optimize it will slove your problem and also it will be more maintable and flexible for update.

Comment: @Chlebta the problem is, that unfortunately that is the simplified version due to the information that'll we'll need to manage and maintain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll be honest I'm just learning how to do this myself, but http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application has been very helpful.